# Binary tree traversals reversed

Tags: algorithms, trees, binary-trees, graph-traversal

Am I correct in saying that

```
traverse(node):
    if node is null, return
    print node
    traverse(node's right subtree)
    traverse(node's left subtree)
```

would produce output that is the reverse of post-order traversal?

```
post-order(node):
    if node is null, return
    post-order(node's left subtree)
    post-order(node's right subtree)
    print node
```

I am mostly interested because if this is true, it greatly simplifies the iterative method for post-order traversal. It "feels" right with a hand-wavey explanation - and with testing on some trees - but how would I prove it?

Comment: What have you tried towards proving that your algorithm is correct and where did you get stuck? (Also, I don't see how this simplifies anything.)

Comment: See http://leetcode.com/2010/10/binary-tree-post-order-traversal.html regarding simplification. 
I thought of using induction, with a base case of a single leaf and the main logical step as "if the left and right subtrees are ordered properly...", but I'm not convinced it is sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you are right. If the post order of a tree is "left-recursion, right-recursion, root" then the reverse is "root, reverse-right-recursion, reverse-left-recursion", which is exactly what you propose. Technically the proof would state "by induction on the structure of the tree".